# How can I test that a Perl program compiles from my test suite?

Tags: perl, testing

I'm building a regression system (*not* unit testing) for some Perl scripts.

A core component of the system is

```
  `perl script.pl @params 1>stdoutfile 2>stderrfile`;
```

However, in the course of actually working on the scripts, they sometimes don't compile(Shock!). But *perl* itself will execute correctly. However, I don't know how to detect on stderr whether Perl failed to compile (and therefore wrote to stderr), or my script barfed on input (and therefore wrote to stderr).

How do I detect whether a program executed or not, without exhaustively finding Perl error messages and grepping the stderr file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be easiest to do this in two steps:

```
system('$^X -c script.pl');
if ($? == 0) {
    # it compiled, now let's see if it runs
    system('$^X script.pl', @params, '1>stdoutfile', '2>stderrfile');
    # check $?
}
else {
    warn "script.pl didn't compile";
}
```

Note the use of [`$^X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24EXECUTABLE_NAME) instead of `perl`. This is more flexible and robust. It ensures that you're running from the same installation instead of whatever interpreter shows up first in your path. The system call will inherit your environment (including PERL5LIB), so spawning a different version of perl could result in hard-to-diagnose compatibility errors.

Comment: You should always use $^X. I've been bitten by a hard-coded 'perl' almost every time I've used it. The problem is that that the child process inherits your PERL5LIB, which might be wrong for the first perl in the PATH. You end up with odd library mismatch errors that way.

Comment: Heh. That's ugly. While it won't always matter (Windows users are unlikely to have multiple versions of Perl installed) it should never be harmful to use $^X. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Michael Carman Ah-em ... I have Cygwin, Strawberry and ActiveState Perl as well as one I compiled from scratch using VC Express.

Comment: @Sinan Unur: I have several versions as well, but I think that puts us squarely in the minority.

Answer (score 3):

When I want to check that a program compiles, I check that it compiles :)

Here's what I put into *t/compile.t* to run with the rest of my test suite. It stops all testing with the "bail out" if the script does not compile:

```
use Test::More tests => 1;

my $file = '...';

print "bail out! Script file is missing!" unless -e $file;

my $output = `$^X -c $file 2>&1`;

print "bail out! Script file does not compile!"
    unless like( $output, qr/syntax OK$/, 'script compiles' );
```

Comment: Test::More has a BAIL_OUT() function.

Answer (score 3):

Scripts are notoriously hard to test.  You have to run them and then scrape their output.  You can't unit test their guts... or can you?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# Only run if we're the file being executed by Perl
main() if $0 eq __FILE__;

sub main {
    ...your code here...
}

1;
```

Now you can load the script like any other library.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Test::More;

require_ok("./script.pl");
```

You can even run and test main().  [Test::Output](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::Output) is handy for capturing the output.  You can say `local @ARGV` to control arguments or you can change main() to take @ARGV as an argument (recommended).

Then you can start splitting main() up into smaller routines which you can easily unit test.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to edit the script. This is a black-box test approach, not a unit test approach(which has its own time and place).

Comment: You're not doing just blackbox.  By testing the program through the command line you're doing high level acceptance testing.  JUST high level acceptance testing.  These tests are harder to write since you have to test everything through lots of intermediate code.  And when something goes wrong it can be any one of 9381 things.  You lose much of the benefit of testing while coding.  And you already said you're working on the scripts, so its not like that's set in stone.  Finally, I wanted to give you another approach rather than just a variant on everyone else's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `$?` variable.

From `perldoc perlvar`:

> The status returned by the last pipe
>   close, backtick ("``") command,
>   successful call to wait() or
>   waitpid(), or from the system()
>   operator.  This is just the 16-bit
>   status word returned by the
>   traditional Unix wait() system call
>   (or else is made up to look like it). 
>   Thus, the exit value of the subprocess
>   is really ("$? >> 8"), and "$? & 127"
>   gives which signal, if any, the
>   process died from, and "$? & 128"
>   reports whether there was a core dump.

Comment: But does $? return the result from *perl* or the *script*? And what are the Perl return values - I wasn't able to find it when I googled.

Comment: It could be either. If you want to check that the script compiles, run `perl -c script.pl` instead and test for $? == 0.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need [`IPC::Open3`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html).